# 〇〇さん「は・が」いらっしゃいますか？

Tags: particle-は, particle-が, keigo, business-japanese, は-and-が

I found this sentence on https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%81%A3%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%82%8B and it struck me as odd.

> 山田【やまだ】さん**が**いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Listening to my co-workers (business phone calls) I've noticed that most times they will drop the particle completely and I don't believe that I have ever heard them use 「が」. As a point of reference I would probably say something like 「〇〇さん、いらっしゃいますでしょうか？」.

My question: Is there a semantic difference between using 「は・が」or nothing at all? Also beyond the base semantics are there any connotations to using 〇〇さん「が・は」？

Comment: 山田さんがいらっしゃいますか is seeking anyone whose name happens to be Yamada, not seeking a certain person called Yamada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence:

> 「[山田]{やまだ}さん**が**いらっしゃいますでしょう**か**。」

is definitely more than weird and it is nothing native speakers would say.  The particle needs to be 「は」, and never 「が」.

**To ask if someone is in, the topic marker is always 「は」**.  Admittedly, though, using 「が」 to do so is a very common mistake among Japanese-learners.

There is, however, a situation in which 「Name + が」 can be used with 「いらっしゃる/いらっしゃいます」 ***in a statement*** if not a question.  That is when you have just seen or found someone and want to tell another person that he is here/there.  You will say:

> 「山田さん**が**いらっしゃいます。」

This is completely correct and you cannot use 「は」 here.

Comment: I've heard that you can use 「は」to contrast that something is here but something else isn't here. Ex: プリンターはあるけどパソコンがない… Is this same grammar point usable for people? Ex: 田中さんはいますがジョンさんがいません。

Comment: @Leo you should use は after both things, not は and then が

Comment: ^ weird al, 「プリンターはあるけどパソコン**は**ない」/「プリンターはあるけどパソコン**が**ない」、「田中さんはいますがジョンさん**は**いません」/「田中さんはいますがジョンさん**が**いません」 ... Both versions sound okay. They'd be used in different situations.

Comment: Would you still call that a contrastive usage? If so, what's the difference?